# Selenium looping the confirmation pop up using IE driver

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to automate the process which is containing multiple web elements & clicking the each web element , it'll popup confirmation alert & need to accept that confirmation. 
Issue here is , the code is working for 5 , 6 elements after the it got struck. sharing the below code,

```
int number=Integer.parseInt(str1[10]);
int n;
System.out.println(number);
for( n = 1 ; n <= number ; n++)
    {
     try
      {
       driver.findElementByXPath("//div[contains(@class,'groupbox')]/div[contains(@class,'groupboxContent')]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/span[contains(@class,'resourceActions')]/a[1]/img[contains(@title,'Undo check out')]").click();
       Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       alert.accept();
    }
    catch(NoAlertPresentException e)
    {

    }
    catch(UnhandledAlertException e)
    {

    }
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, idea is to wait for the alert

```
int number=Integer.parseInt(str1[10]);
int n;
WebDriverWait _wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
System.out.println(number);
for( n = 1 ; n <= number ; n++)
    {
     try
      {
       driver.findElementByXPath("//div[contains(@class,'groupbox')]/div[contains(@class,'groupboxContent')]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/span[contains(@class,'resourceActions')]/a[1]/img[contains(@title,'Undo check out')]").click();
       _wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
       Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
       //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       alert.accept();
    }
    catch(NoAlertPresentException e)
    {

    }
    catch(UnhandledAlertException e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jyothishwar , i tried using wait , it was not working ..but with your alert present condition , it is working fine.

Comment: If it solves the issue can you mark as answered .. it will be helpful :-)

Comment: sure http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work